# Datagrid `TopLeftHeaderCell` is missing from the properties panel

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am looking for the `TopLeftHeaderCell` property of my `DataGridView` and it is missing from the designer:

[image: Properties panel in Visual Studio without the property]

However, when I set it in the code, it works perfectly. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code or [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.topleftheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx), you see that the property has the attribute `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]` set.

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public DataGridViewHeaderCell TopLeftHeaderCell { get; set; }
```

This specifically prevents the Designer from showing this property.

As for why this was decided by Microsoft: There is no chance to fill the grid with data at design time. The data is only there at runtime, so what cell would you assign at design time when there are none available?

Comment: Thanks. Why did Microsoft choose to do that?

Comment: Thanks. But isn't this specific cell a part of the headers, which are set in design time, rather than a data cell?

Comment: @Sipo If you look into the *.designer.cs file for the form, you see that there are columns defined for the grid, but no cells. The Cell objects are only created at runtime.

Comment: So why is it a considered a cell and not the header of the left column?